# Safari not honouring the translate="no" for input feilds

Tags: javascript, html, safari, translation

I have a straightforward Japanese HTML form with the 'translate="no"' attribute set at the document level. When a user attempts to use Safari's translation option, the static content remains untranslated, as intended. However, the text within the input fields gets converted to English, which is not the desired behavior.

How can I prevent Safari from translating the content within input fields?"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja-jp" translate="no">
<body>

<h1>姓</h1>

<form >
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
</form>
<script>document.getElementById("fname").value="姓"</script>

<p>姓 姓姓姓姓 姓 姓".</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Use [this](https://turquoise-sonnnie-1.tiiny.site) link to open in safari and click the translate button in the address bar. Notice that the content inside the input box get translated.

Comment: Raised - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=270495